# Can I update a value in table in remote Mysql DB using Pyspark?

Tags: python, mysql, pyspark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql

I am reading from remote mysql database using kafka , and pass it to Pyspark streaming to apply sentiment analysis and then update the column in ht e mysql database with the value. and is that the best case scenario or there is an architecture efficient than that

Comment: Apologies, but I believe that this question might be too broad for StackOverflow. Could you go into more detail about what you think may be inefficient, or what improvements in efficiency you're hoping for?

Comment: Using spark to update in MySql database. as I have searched a lot on the internet for the same case but i didn't find a snippet code for that. So I though that may be there is a better solution to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit vague, but here goes.

Yes, you can write a Spark DataFrame into any `jdbc` database using `df.write.jdbc()`. Here's the doc https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=jdbc#pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.jdbc

Your code would look like such

```
url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/foobar"

properties = {
    "user": "foo",
    "password": "bar"
}

df.write.jdbc(url=url, table="tablename", mode="overwrite", properties=properties)
```

This gives you four write modes:

> append: Append contents of this DataFrame to existing data.
>
> overwrite: Overwrite existing data.
>
> ignore: Silently ignore this operation if data already exists.
>
> error or errorifexists (default case): Throw an exception if data already exists.

Alternatively, since you're using Spark Streaming, why not produce your dataframe changelog as a new topic and sync this table using a tool like *Kafka Connect* to your `mysql` database. This leaves you with perhaps a bit more control over how you insert/update/upsert data to your table.